# No me Esta Mostrando Componente en multiple componente Angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-router

En mi aplicación tengo multiples componentes y uno es Productos y que se encuentra en el app.module
y mi producto.module.ts  (InicioProductosComponent si lo muestra)tengo las siguientes líneas:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionComponent } from './DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion/desarrollo-tecnologico-innovacion.component';
import { InicioProductosComponent } from './inicio-productos/inicio-productos.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'inicio-productos',
    component: InicioProductosComponent
  }
  ,
    {
    path: 'DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion',
    component: DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductosRoutingModule { }
```

En el modulo DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion
se genero de esta forma:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionModule } from './desarrollo-tecnologico-innovacion.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion',
    component: DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionModule
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/productos', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionRoutingModule { }
```

pero al navegar y colocar la ruta en el browser:

> http://localhost:4200/DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion

no me muestra el componente de que esta ubicado en esta carpeta.. **DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacion**

Mi conocimiento en angular es poco, así que no se si en algo estoy fallando.

Comment: En las rutas (`path`), estás colocando textos vacíos. Angular no recoge las rutas según estructura de proyecto/carpetas, sino según declaración explícita de las rutas. Intenta asignar algún valor en los `path`. Puedes revisar la [documentación](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) para más detalles.

Comment: @KBeDev ya modifique la pregunta, igual me sale un error core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'productos'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu routes array debería contener una lista de objetos con 2 propiedades, path, que define el URL para la ruta, y component, que define el componente que Angular debe usar para esa ruta. Dicho esto, tienes un error en tu DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionRoutingModule, estás asignando DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionModule en lugar de DesarrolloTecnologicoInnovacionComponent

Comment: :| lo que pasa con copy paste!

Comment: no te sientas mal, a todos nos pasa jaja